# How to block access to .bashrc and .profile

Tags: debian, security, nginx, bashrc, profile

How can I block possibility to download .bashrc and .profile files from Debian server with Nginx?

I already added this to vhosts configuration:

```
  location ~* \.(bashrc|profile)$ {
      deny all;
  }
```

I also changed **chmod** from default **644** to **600** on this files to make it more secure.

Unfortunately, files are still avaliable to download from web browser.

I thought Nginx configuration I already added will be enough, but it's not and cound't figure out what else am I missing.

Comment: Why does your document-root have those files in the first place??

Comment: I am quite new in Nginx, so not sure if doing it right, but should I change it to this? -> location ~* /\.(bashrc|profile)$ { deny all; }